# MySQL. Как переписать auto_increment по порядку

Tags: mysql, sql

друзья.

Тяжело было правильно задать заголовок, потому что дело вот в чем...
Есть таблица, в которой, с какого-то дуба, задали SERIAL (Auto_increment) с 300.000.000 и соответственно при добавление строки поле id становится 300.000.001 и т.д.

В связи с этим вопрос, можно ли перезаписать (или переписать) существующую таблицу так, чтобы SERIAL начинался с 1? Возможно есть какая-то команда в SQL?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE serial AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` только имейте ввиду, он при генерации следующего значения не проверяет отсутствия такого в БД. И когда он дойдет до уже существующего значения в 300млн возникнет проблема

Comment: Ну да, это понятно, но мне бы желательно чтобы все эти в 300 млн поменялись и начались с 1-го

Comment: Гм.. а чем помешали такие значения? ведь синтетический PK используется только для организации связей и в принципе не должен быть виден конечному пользователю - а коли так, то какая разница, сколько там цифр?

Comment: К сожалению Бог послал кривого программера, который написал такой скрипт, что он строго привязан к айдишнику в БД. По началу проблем небыло, т.к на сайтах в БД было всё хорошо и по порядку от 1, а на одном сайте что-то пошло не так... и вот имеем 300 млн айдишник, который долго и нудно обрабатывается оператором "for"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Разорвать все связи (автоинкремент — он же так-то не нужен, только для связей; значит, есть и связанные таблицы)
2. В каждой связанной таблице update set поле=поле-299999999
3. И потом только удалить первичный ключ и аналогично с нужной таблицей.
4. И не забыть восстановить удалённое.

Comment: Ну да, связи есть :-) Спасибо за мысль с UPDATE

Answer (score 2):

Можно так сделать

1. Удалить у поля автоинкремент и первичный ключ.
2. Обнулить значение поля.
3. Заново установить автоинкремент.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: По-моему, проще тупо грохнуть поле и затем создать заново...